# Vee-validate 3 and Bootstrap 3 form error styling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, vee-validate

How can I add the `has-error` style to the wrapping div of a Bootstrap 3 input?

So this doesn't validate because the ValidationProvider component won't find the input:

```
<!-- doesn't work because the provider can't find the input -->
<ValidationProvider v-slot="{ errors }">
    <div :class="{'form-group': true, 'has-error': errors.lenght > 0}">
        <label for="credit-card">
            Card Number
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="credit-card" class="form-control" data-stripe="number" v-model="paymentForm.creditCard.number"/>
    </div>
</ValidationProvider>
```

So this validates, but I can't access the wrapping div and check the `{{errors[0}}` there.

```
<!-- this won't work, obviously -->
<div :class="{'form-group': true, 'has-error': errors.lenght > 0}">
    <ValidationProvider v-slot="{ errors }">
        <label for="credit-card">
            Card Number
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="credit-card" class="form-control" data-stripe="number" v-model="paymentForm.creditCard.number"/>
    </ValidationProvider>
</div>
```

How can I get the `has-error` class in the wrapping div using vee-validate without re-inventing the wheel and doing a lot of custom code around it to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried the slim prop? https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/api/validation-provider.html#forcing-renderless

Comment: @TroyKessler sorry but I don't see how this would help me with my problem in any way? Can you please elaborate this with an example?

Comment: Ok I've tried to replicate this but it works perfectly for me... did you add the rules to the ValidationProvider? They are missing in your example

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, "lenght" instead of "length", and the " > 0" is not mandatory.
The first example should be ok.

```
<ValidationProvider v-slot="{ errors }">
    <div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error': errors.length}">
        <label for="credit-card">
            Card Number
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="credit-card" class="form-control" data-stripe="number" v-model="paymentForm.creditCard.number"/>
    </div>
</ValidationProvider>
```